# How to show latest data on your app from a web server

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, backend

I have a parse.com backend and a swift ios8 app.

What is the best way for the apps that use the backend to be notified of changes to a certain table so that a collection view can reload its data?

Data is added to the db from one of the apps not via the website.

Would I need to setup push notifications? Or would I do regular checks from the app To see if data has changed? Or is there another way?

Comment: Cloud code and push notifications are probably the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use push notifications is the better way to achieve your goal.
Here's the steps:

1.Data added from another app to the db in your backend

2.Your backend shoud post a push notification to all your app

3.when your app received the notification, it must pull the newest data from backend and refresh the view in app

Regular checking from app will has a bad influence on you app's performance, so do not use this way if possible.